# Compilation error VTK, C++

Tags: c++, linux, vtk

I am trying to compile to compile the project "volumemorph" given in http://cs.uccs.edu/~gsc/pub/master/kchandra/src/
following the instructions given in http://cs.uccs.edu/~gsc/pub/master/kchandra/src/Read_Me.txt

The VTK installation was done by following the instructions of VTK wiki for linux systems.

At compilation of the volumemorph project I get the following message:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/axlia/volumemorph'
Making all in volumemorph
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/axlia/volumemorph/volumemorph'
source='CADisplayEngine.cpp' object='CADisplayEngine.o' libtool=no \
    depfile='.deps/CADisplayEngine.Po' tmpdepfile='.deps/CADisplayEngine.TPo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../admin/depcomp \
    g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..     -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-long-long -Wundef -Wall -pedantic -W -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -ansi -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_BSD_SOURCE -Wcast-align -Wconversion -O2 -fno-exceptions -fno-check-new  -c -o CADisplayEngine.o `test -f 'CADisplayEngine.cpp' || echo './'`CADisplayEngine.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wmissing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from CADisplayEngine.cpp:18:0:
CADisplayEngine.h: In member function ‘float CADisplayEngine::getRenderTimeInSeconds()’:
CADisplayEngine.h:80:79: warning: conversion to ‘float’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
CADisplayEngine.cpp: In member function ‘void CADisplayEngine::initialize(int, int)’:
CADisplayEngine.cpp:68:16: error: ‘class vtkVolumeRayCastMapper’ has no member named ‘SetInput’
CADisplayEngine.cpp: In member function ‘void CADisplayEngine::render(CAVolume*)’:
CADisplayEngine.cpp:117:13: error: ‘class vtkJPEGWriter’ has no member named ‘SetInput’
CADisplayEngine.cpp: In member function ‘bool CADisplayEngine::saveImageFile()’:
CADisplayEngine.cpp:196:6: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
make[2]: *** [CADisplayEngine.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/axlia/volumemorph/volumemorph'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/axlia/volumemorph'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am pretty sure that the code should work but I can't compile it and I am stuck, any help? how am I supposed to fix it?

PS I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and I am a new linux user.

Comment: If you're using VTK6, you need to change a couple of those SetInput calls to SetInputData.

Answer (score 0):

The readme says that it requires VTK 4.2. Are you sure that you are using exactly this version? Because Ubuntu 12.10 [seems to pack version 5.8](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vtk).

Your options are:

- Find, download VTK 4.2, compile it and use your private copy instead of the system one.
- Find an updated version of *volumemorph* that works with your VTK version.
- Learn the differences between VTK 4.2 and 5.8 and patch the *volumemorph* yourself!